# how to backup a specific table oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, backup, plsqldeveloper

I want to have a backup of a specific table because a I want to change one of it's field, if changes don't work, apply the backup and restore the initial state. I'm using plsql developer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is CTAS (Create Table As Select), i.e.

```
create table my_table_backup as select * From my_table;
```

Or, use **Data Pump** Export / Import utilities. Or, as it is just a single table, the *original* EXP / IMP utilities might also work.

Or, **spool** data into a CSV file and load it back using SQL*Loader (or external tables feature).

Quite a few options; I'd start with option 1 (CTAS).

Comment: The *simplest* option would be to do nothing and then use `flashback table` if necessary.  But that operation has some caveats and is not always reliable, so you'd want to create a backup anyway, in case flashback doesn't work.